# Moving MSVS solution and project without moving source files

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to move MSVS solution and project files to nested folder withut mving source files. THe original structure is:

```
 - [root]
 + solution.sln
 + - common
     + - sources
 + - project1 
     + - sources
     + project1.vsprj 
 + - project2 
     + - src
     + project2.vsprj
 + - project3 
     + - sources
     + project3.vsprj
```

I want separate build tool files from actual source, and look  somethign similar to

```
 - [root]
 + - common
     + - sources
 + - project1 
     + - sources
 + - project2 
     + - sources
 + - project3 
     + - sources
 + - build
     + - vs20XX
          + solution.sln
          + project1.vsprj
          + project2.vsprj
          + project3.vsprj
```

Is this doable easility without editing and replacing every file? Whole solution is nearly 12000 files , some with custom build steps, files in `common` folder are used by every project. If not, could it be done by some script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're migrating from a Windows environment to a Linux one (Linux people like to have their source files all in one place and Build/IDE-specific files all together).

If you aren't moving source files you should be fine. You'll just have to re-link/tell the solution where the projects moved (Remove old project refs, then "Add Existing Project") with the new project locations relative to the solutions new location.

Generally, solutions contain references to projects and projects contain references to source files. Moving a solution around is fine if the projects don't move, and moving projects around is fine if you tell the solution where it moved. You do have to do a little work in re-referencing paths to everything in the properties of the projects since VS works with paths relative to the $(Solution Dir) or %(Project Dir).

For future reference, I recommend setting up and adding custom Property Sheets to the projects so any path changes can be migrated as projects move around in one step.

Comment: multi-platform, but nothing to do with migration to new platform. Actually modern version control tools and build chains are badly accustomed to the fact that VisualStuio creates some temporal and configuration files everywhere around the project. Solution can contain files too (aka "solution items") Files contain relative paths from project %(Project Dir) location. It's not clear how to change $(Solution Dir) or %(Project Dir), that seems to be always location of file?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, `$(SolutionDir)` and `%(ProjectDir)` always contain the current location of the file(s). You can change the Temporary Directory to force VS to put those config/temporal files in one place.